# Error using mex: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, xcode, macos, matlab, mex

I'm trying to use C-Code in a Matlab programm. The C-Code basically decodes a Datamatrix Code and give you the matching String. The code has around 17 c-files.

On a windows-machine i can compile the the c-code and the programm is running perfectly. When i try the same on my Macbook Pro i always get this Error:

```
Error using mex
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_square", referenced from:
        _dist2_float in findBiggestEnclosedArea.o
        _dist3_float in findBiggestEnclosedArea.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Error in make (line 76)
    mex -g -DNDEBUG -DMATLAB decodeDatamatrix_mex.c...
```

This is my compile command:

```
mex -g -DNDEBUG -DMATLAB decodeDatamatrix_mex.c...
        decode_datamatrix/decodeDatamatrix.c...
        decode_datamatrix/imResize.c...
        decode_datamatrix/otsu.c ...
        decode_datamatrix/findBiggestEnclosedArea.c ...
        decode_datamatrix/label.c ...
        decode_datamatrix/floodfill.c...
        decode_datamatrix/getRegion.c...
        decode_datamatrix/edges.c...
        decode_datamatrix/findParameters.c...
        decode_datamatrix/firstHoughTransform.c ...
        decode_datamatrix/secondHoughTransform.c ...
        decode_datamatrix/getDatamatrixGrid.c ...
        decode_datamatrix/CorrectErrs.c ...
        decode_datamatrix/dmtxdecodescheme.c...
        decode_datamatrix/placement.c...
        decode_datamatrix/dmsize.c
```

Here is the complete logfile:

```
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'Xcode with Clang' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'DEVELOPER_DIR' ...No.
... Executing command 'xcode-select -print-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer').
... Looking for folder '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'which xcrun' ...Yes ('/usr/bin/xcrun').
... Looking for folder '/usr/bin' ...Yes.
... Executing command 'defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense' ...No.
... Executing command 'defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEXcodeVersionForAgreedToGMLicense' ...Yes ('9.0').
... Executing command '
agreed=9.0 
 if echo $agreed | grep -E '[\.\"]' >/dev/null; then 
 lhs=`expr "$agreed" : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` 
  rhs=`expr "$agreed" : '[0-9]*[\.]\(.*\)$'` 
 if echo $rhs | grep -E '[\."]' >/dev/null; then 
 rhs=`expr "$rhs" : '\([0-9]*\)[\.].*'` 
 fi 
 if [ $lhs -gt 4 ] || ( [ $lhs -eq 4 ] && [ $rhs -ge 3 ] ); then 
 echo $agreed 
 else 
 exit 1
 fi 
 fi' ...Yes ('9.0').
... Executing command 'xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path' ...Yes ('/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk').
... Executing command 'xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-version' ...Yes ('10.13').
Found installed compiler 'Xcode with Clang'.
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    Compiler location: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    Options file: /Users/fabian/Library/Application Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2017b/mex_C_maci64.xml
    CMDLINE200 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" decodeDatamatrix_mex.o decodeDatamatrix.o imResize.o otsu.o findBiggestEnclosedArea.o label.o floodfill.o getRegion.o edges.o findParameters.o firstHoughTransform.o secondHoughTransform.o getDatamatrixGrid.o CorrectErrs.o dmtxdecodescheme.o placement.o dmsize.o c_mexapi_version.o  -g -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"  -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++ -o decodeDatamatrix_mex.mexmaci64
    CC : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang
    CXX : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang++
    DEFINES : -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
    MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
    MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET : 10.9
    CFLAGS : -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk
    INCLUDE : -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include"
    COPTIMFLAGS : -O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG
    CDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    LD : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang
    LDXX : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang++
    LDFLAGS : -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    LDBUNDLE : -bundle 
    FUNCTIONMAP : "/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    VERSIONMAP : "/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKEXPORT : -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map"
    LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"
    LINKLIBS : -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++
    LDOPTIMFLAGS : -O
    LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
    OBJEXT : .o
    LDEXT : .mexmaci64
    SETENV : CC="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang"
                CXX="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang++"
                CFLAGS="-fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE"
                CXXFLAGS="-fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -fobjc-arc -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE"
                COPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
                CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG"
                CDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
                CXXDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
                LD="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang"
                LDXX="/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang++"
                LDFLAGS="-Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++ -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map""
                LDDEBUGFLAGS="-g"
    DEVELOPER_DIR_CHECK : 
    XCODE_DIR : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    XCRUN_DIR : /usr/bin
    XCODE_AGREED_VERSION : 9.0
    ISYSROOT : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk
    SDKVER : 10.13
    MATLABROOT : /Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app
    ARCH : maci64
    SRC : "/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decodeDatamatrix_mex.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/decodeDatamatrix.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/imResize.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/otsu.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/findBiggestEnclosedArea.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/label.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/floodfill.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/getRegion.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/edges.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/findParameters.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/firstHoughTransform.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/secondHoughTransform.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/getDatamatrixGrid.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/CorrectErrs.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/dmtxdecodescheme.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/placement.c";"/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/dmsize.c";"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c"
    OBJ : decodeDatamatrix_mex.o;decodeDatamatrix.o;imResize.o;otsu.o;findBiggestEnclosedArea.o;label.o;floodfill.o;getRegion.o;edges.o;findParameters.o;firstHoughTransform.o;secondHoughTransform.o;getDatamatrixGrid.o;CorrectErrs.o;dmtxdecodescheme.o;placement.o;dmsize.o;c_mexapi_version.o
    OBJS : decodeDatamatrix_mex.o decodeDatamatrix.o imResize.o otsu.o findBiggestEnclosedArea.o label.o floodfill.o getRegion.o edges.o findParameters.o firstHoughTransform.o secondHoughTransform.o getDatamatrixGrid.o CorrectErrs.o dmtxdecodescheme.o placement.o dmsize.o c_mexapi_version.o 
    SRCROOT : /Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decodeDatamatrix_mex
    DEF : /var/folders/xl/t0pk0jl56gj75637l3cq1h7h0000gn/T/mex_1191751144668386_17812/decodeDatamatrix_mex.def
    EXP : decodeDatamatrix_mex.exp
    LIB : decodeDatamatrix_mex.lib
    EXE : decodeDatamatrix_mex.mexmaci64
    ILK : decodeDatamatrix_mex.ilk
    MANIFEST : decodeDatamatrix_mex.mexmaci64.manifest
    TEMPNAME : decodeDatamatrix_mex
    EXEDIR : 
    EXENAME : decodeDatamatrix_mex
    OPTIM : -g
    LINKOPTIM : -g
    CMDLINE100_0 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -c -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -g "/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decodeDatamatrix_mex.c" -o decodeDatamatrix_mex.o
    CMDLINE100_1 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -c -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -g "/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/decodeDatamatrix.c" -o decodeDatamatrix.o
    CMDLINE100_2 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -c -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -g "/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/imResize.c" -o imResize.o
    .
    .
    .
    CMDLINE100_17 : /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -c -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -g "/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/version/c_mexapi_version.c" -o c_mexapi_version.o
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'Xcode with Clang'.
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -c -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -g "/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decodeDatamatrix_mex.c" -o decodeDatamatrix_mex.o
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -c -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -g "/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/decodeDatamatrix.c" -o decodeDatamatrix.o
.
.
.
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -c -DNDEBUG  -DMATLAB  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/include" -I"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/simulink/include" -fno-common -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -fexceptions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -g "/Users/fabian/Documents/Diplomarbeit/BA_Tecan/Matlab-Code/Functions/Datamatrix_decoder/decode_datamatrix/findParameters.c" -o findParameters.o
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk macosx10.13 clang -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -bundle  -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map" decodeDatamatrix_mex.o decodeDatamatrix.o imResize.o otsu.o findBiggestEnclosedArea.o label.o floodfill.o getRegion.o edges.o findParameters.o firstHoughTransform.o secondHoughTransform.o getDatamatrixGrid.o CorrectErrs.o dmtxdecodescheme.o placement.o dmsize.o c_mexapi_version.o  -g -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/extern/lib/maci64/c_exportsmexfileversion.map"  -L"/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64" -lmx -lmex -lmat -lc++ -o decodeDatamatrix_mex.mexmaci64
```

Any idea where the error could be?

Comment: Where is `square_` defined? Is it a Windows-specific function? Or is it defined somewhere in your project? In the latter case, make sure you put the file that defines it *after* the file that uses it. That's how the UNIX linker works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working when I compiled without the -g parameter:

```
mex -DNDEBUG -DMATLAB decodeDatamatrix_mex.c...
```

Any idea why this works?